# what is the "spot a phrase"

Tags: phrases

I'm learning English from BBC 6 minutes English. I got this sentence and tried to research the phrase but I don't understand what it means. Please help me explain it.

Can you **spot a phrase** that means a limit or an ending?
source : https://www.voicetube.com/videos/27105#view-mode

Answer (score 1):

`Spot a phrase` in this context means "identify a phrase which satisfies the described conditions". Such tasks train you to match definitions and descriptions with common phrases, terms and idioms; find synonymic words and phrases.